# How to clear cache using CacheConfiguration in Apache ignite

Tags: java, spring, apache, caching

Not able to destroy the cache after some duration time using Spring CacheConfiguration in Apache Ignite.After 40 seconds cache should be cleared.

Please see the below Code.

```
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="myCache" />
                        <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
                        <property name="backups" value="1" />
                        <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                        <property name="expiryPolicyFactory"ref="createdExpiryPolicyForDay"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="createdExpiryPolicyForDay" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf" >
<constructor-arg type="javax.cache.expiry.Duration" ref="durationForDay"/>
<constructor-arg type="javax.cache.expiry.Duration" >
<util:constant static-field="javax.cache.expiry.Duration.FIVE_MINUTES"/>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean name="durationForDay" class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration" > 
<constructor-arg name="timeUnit" value="SECONDS" /> 
<constructor-arg name="durationAmount" value="40"/>
</bean>
```

Please help us, we are stuck with this issue

Comment: I'm confused that factory method "javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy.factofyOf()" takes 2 arguments.


It looks like there should be only one argument:
 public static Factory<ExpiryPolicy> factoryOf(Duration duration)